# Facebook Page Plugin not updating

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk

I have had the facebook page plugin on my clients site for a while now.

Every so often it will stop displaying the newest posts.

I previously had the iframe version and have now switched to the Javascript SDK version.

It makes no difference. It is not displaying the newest posts from last week.

How can this bee fixed?

The Chrome console displays

`Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/xti.php?xt=AZW3DuNaDpiwMnJrv76Q1eHoFMxs_pdt6ww3PjjZU6YRh8khjSvF3DKqeCkrFQL1LDw-16BPJFvOlCoBJaBE-wHCuKIsfmop4qc9p9le1wOPRqTjPD9hNZ0LLZs-lv3DgAeAOJ7dfmEEhX-3yakKNCFE1tJm7rIKlh7CWA2zuj-ATQ&isv=1&cts=1509375217&csp' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

Edit - example - http://letchworthmotorauctions.co.uk/

Comment: Live example please.

Comment: @CBroe sorry, this has been added.

Comment: The two posts currently shown on top of the page seem to be Photo posts; might be that only “normal” posts are shown in the page plugin.

Comment: @CBroe I dont think thats it. The other posts have photos and they show.

Comment: Yeah, you’re right. Looks like the “missing” posts are targeted to specific audiences (trying to request them via API with an app access token gives "unsupported GET request"), which will make them not show up in page plugin.

Comment: @CBroe do you know how I make them not target specific audiences?

Comment: Check the page settings, and ask the page admin making the posts whether they are specifically doing anything in that regard.